# Still pretty confused with Argument Principle, Rouche's Theorem and Winding number

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are analytic inside and on a simple closed curve
>   $C$ and that $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$ for all $z$ on $C$. Then $f(z)$ and
>   $f(z) + g(z)$ have the same number of zeros, counting multiplicities
>   inside $C$.
>
> Proof: Note first that if $f(z) = h(z) \cdot k(z)$, then
>   $$\dfrac{f^{'}(z)}{f(z)} = \dfrac{h^{'}(z)}{h(z)}+
>  \dfrac{k^{'}(z)}{k(z)}$$
>
> So that we have $$\int_{C}\dfrac{f^{'}(z)}{f(z)}dz =
>  \int_{C}\dfrac{h^{'}(z)}{h(z)}dz  + \int_{C}\dfrac{k^{'}(z)}{k(z)}dz$$
>
> Thus if we write $$f(z) + g(z) = f(z) \cdot \left(1+
>  \frac{g(z)}{f(z)}\right)$$
>
> It follows from the Argument Principle that the number of zeros of
>   $f+g$ in $C$ is evaluated as
>
> $\begin{aligned} Z(f+g) & = \dfrac{1}{2\pi
>  i}\int_{C}\dfrac{(f+g)^{'}}{f+g}dz\\   & = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}
>  \dfrac{f^{'}(1+\frac{g}{f})+f(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{f(1+\frac{g}{f})}dz\\
>    &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \dfrac{f^{'}}{f}dz + \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}
>  \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz\\   &= Z(f)  +
>  \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}
>  \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz\\ \end{aligned}$
>
> Note that $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}
>  \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz =
>  \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\Delta\text{Arg}\left(1+\dfrac{g}{f}\right)$$
>
> Let $h(z) = 1+\dfrac{g(z)}{f(z)}$.
>
> Since $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\Delta\text{Arg}(h(z))$ is the winding number 
>   of $h(z)$ about the origin. It suffices to just find the winding
>   number of $h(z)$ about the origin and we are done.
>
> For all $z$ on the boundary of $C$, we have the property that $$|g| <
>  |f| \Rightarrow \left|\dfrac{g}{f}\right|<1 \Rightarrow 
>  \left|\left(\dfrac{g}{f}+1\right) -1\right|<1$$
>
> This implies that the image of the boundary of $C$ will be the
>   boundary of a ball $B(1,1)$ on the $w$ plane when mapping through the
>   function $h(z)$. It follows that $h(z)$ is inside $B(1,1)$. Since the
>   image of $C$ does not enclose $0$, it follows that the winding number
>   is $0$ as the image of $C$ will not wind into account $0$. And hence
>   $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}
>  \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz =
>  \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\Delta\text{Arg}\left(1+\dfrac{g}{f}\right)=0$$

Thus our result follows and proof is complete.This is a proof written by me following my textbooks. Is it correct logic? In addition, another proof i saw uses a transformation of $w = F(z) = 1 + \dfrac{g}{f}$ and the integrand becomes $$\int_{F(C)}\dfrac{1}{w}dw$$ and $F(C)$ is the image of $C$? Is this using the concept of winding numbers or is this just a substitution of integration in complex? I am quite lost as i do not know if substituition is using the concept of winding numbers or not.